# How do I deploy Angular application on Heroku using ng cli?

Tags: heroku, angular-cli, gitlab-ci

I have the following `package.json` :

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "11.13.0",
    "npm": "6.9.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build:prod": "npm run build -- --prod --aot",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^8.0.2",
    "typescript": "3.4.5",
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

and the following `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
before_script:
  - echo "Execute scripts which are required to bootstrap the application. !"

after_script:
  - echo "Clean up activity can be done here !."

# Cache modules in between jobs
cache:
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  paths:
  - node_modules/

stages:
  - deploy

deploy_staging:
  stage: deploy
  image: ruby:2.3
  script:
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
    - gem install dpl
    - dpl --provider=heroku --app=$HEROKU_APP_STAGING --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: https://$HEROKU_APP_STAGING.herokuapp.com
  only:
    - master
```

When I try to deploy my app on Heroku I got a success deployment but it fails when it launches the app :
`sh: 1: ng: not found`.

Is it possible/good to use `ng` on heroku ? What am i missing ?

Answer (score 2):

In `deploy_staging` part of the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, the image `ruby:2.3` will be pulled which does not contain installed `npm` or `angular-cli` (So it can cause `ng: not found` error).
 It seems, you need to add a `build` stage to the `.gitlab-ci.yml` which is assigned for building Angular app and produce bundle files (The `dist` folder in home directory of the Angular app).
For example,  `.gitlab-ci.yml` file might look like this:

```
⋮

stages:
    - build
    - deploy

# New stage for building your Angular app
build_staging:
    stage: build
    image: trion/ng-cli
    allow_failure: false
    script:
        - npm install
        - ng build --prod

deploy_staging:
    stage: deploy
    image: ruby:2.3
    when: on_success
    dependencies: 
        - build
    script:
        - apt-get update -qy
        - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
        - gem install dpl
        - dpl --provider=heroku --app=$HEROKU_APP_STAGING --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY
    environment:
        name: staging
        url: https://$HEROKU_APP_STAGING.herokuapp.com
    only:
        - master

⋮
```